# Storing PHP application settings

Tags: php

Why is it common in PHP to use constants (eg, `define()`) to store things like connection strings? Why not use an `.ini` file and `parse_ini_file`?

Comment: You can store them any way you want - what you perceive as common depends on what tools/framework/convention you're used to. E.g. I don't think I've ever used a constant for a connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants help you use these informations in any included scripts knowing they won't be alterated.

You can as well store these informations in an ini file and load them in variables.

Though these will be constants (they won't change), so it sounds normal to define them as such.